# DataGrid CellEditending event does not return the updated value in the cell

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm trying to get the currently edited and updated item from WPF Datagrid.
This is my code:

```
private void onCellEdit (object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{                
    VML.MyViewModel.CurrentPackage = (MyPackage )e.EditingElement.DataContext;                   
}
```

**Binding Property**

```
Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default
```

Unfortunately this will return the value before editing the cell, the atttibutes are not updated, values available in the EditingElement.DataContext has older values before editing.

Is there a way I can get the edited value without using selectedrowchange event since it won't work with the last row?

Comment: hows your xaml ? any updatetriggers u have ?

Comment: @Muds Updated with binding property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `DataGridTextColumn` you can get edited value by this.

```
( e.EditingElement as TextBox ).Text
```

Comment: um trying to grab the whole entity looking for a way to do that

Comment: @bars222 Do you know how ca we do it if we had the `DatePicker` column?